# How can I setup chrome from the Preferences file to restore the tabs from last session

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, session, restrictions, open

The computer I am using from office has restricted browser. I would like to set up just the option where I can get the tabs from previous session, because it is not available in settings.

I found that I can modify "Preferences" file located in: C:\Users%CURRENT_USER%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Can someone help me identify the setting i need to activate open tabs from previous session?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
"restore_on_startup":1
```

Before you make changes to the Preferences file, make sure you 1. have chrome closed and 2. make a backup copy of said file (or the entire Default dir for that matter, always good to have a fallback copy).

Comment: Thank you. I made a backup. For the values, it appears with codes like this:
restore_on_startup":"C7D3056DB73369E590BD97BBA452CD0EADFBC026AED3C1D02FFB04AEEE30C049"

Comment: afaik these values are generated by your current session, the one above is the on/off switch.